# Logging JSON request with ODataConnectedService

Tags: c#, odata

I'm using https://github.com/odata/ODataConnectedService to communicate with a Business Central server. Everything is working fine. However, I would really like to be able to log the JSON messages sending (and receiving) from the BC server.

Does anybody know how to get the JSON string being send back and forth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the generated `DataServiceContext` has an event called `ReceivingResponse`.

This is my `LogReceivingResponse` (not pretty, but it works):

```
public void LogReceivingResponse(object? sender, ReceivingResponseEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.ResponseMessage is not HttpWebResponseMessage responseMessage)
        {
            return;
        }

        var stream = responseMessage.GetStream();
        var msInput = new MemoryStream();
        stream.CopyTo(msInput);
        msInput.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var str = new StreamReader(msInput);
        var line = str.ReadToEnd();
        line = JsonPrettify(line);

        var uri = responseMessage.Response.ResponseUri;
        Logger.Debug($"Request: {uri}\nResponse: {line}");

        msInput.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        Func<Stream> func = () => msInput;
        responseMessage.GetType().InvokeMember("getResponseStream",
            BindingFlags.SetField | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, responseMessage,
            new object[] { func });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Error(ex, "Failed to log receiving response");
    }
}
```

I suspect you can do something similar with the event `BuildingRequest` for sending data.

Comment: You don't need to do any of this. You can configure request logging at the HttpClient or even System.Net level.